# using react-native-elements for material Icons - does not recognise some of the icons

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements, react-native-vector-icons

using the snack below:
https://snack.expo.io/ry_5rCk84

I am trying to display the icon 'wifi_off' using Material Icons in my react native app (just shared this as a snack on expo for easier sharing) but this is not a recognised value for prop 'name'.
and ends up displaying a '?' for unknown icon.
I am able to use **wifi-off** icon using '**material-community**' icon set

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import {Icon} from 'react-native-elements';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable url.
        </Text>
        <Card>
          <AssetExample />
        </Card>
        <Icon name='wifi' size={50} type='material'/>
        <Icon name='wifi-off' size={50} type='material-community' />
        <Icon name='wifi_off' size={50} type='material' />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`react-native-elements` uses `react-native-vector-icons` to display the icons.

`react-native-vector-icons` has a directory where you can check which icons are available, you can look them up by name. https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/

If you search for all the icons that have **wifi** in their name you find the following result for *MaterialIcons* and *MaterialCommunityIcons*

[image: icons available]

If you search for **wifi_off** you will find that there are no results.

[image]

Therefore **wifi_off** is not available to use.

It is also worth noting that `react-native-elements` currently doesn't support the latest version of `react-native-vector-icons`, you can see that in this currently open [issue](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/issues/1736).

Comment: thanks for clarifying and detailed explanation.
the icon I am looking for doesn't appear to be part of react-native-vector-icons either (not just react-native-elements), while the GitHub document for the package mentions it's using the latest version of Material Icons.

does this mean that not all icons for the version will be included in the package?

Comment: I believe that is the case. I don’t know why it wasn’t included. I guesss that is why they have the directory so you can check which icons are included. You could open another issue on the repo requesting the additional icons be included.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using react native elements Icon, behind the scenes it is searching in a list https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/blob/master/glyphmaps/MaterialIcons.json, here you can find the names of the Icons that are supported and as you can see "wifi_off" is not here, maybe you can try "signal-wifi-off".